# Printing $0 in different ways

Tags: ruby, string-interpolation

Among the following ways to print `$0`, the first one works, yet the second one doesn't. Why?

- Directly

  ```
  puts "current $0 is #{$0}"
  ```
- Constructing `$0` variable name (motivated by javascript)

  ```
  1.times {|i| puts "current $#{i} is #{$i}"}
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the second one is looking for a variable called "$i" not "$0"

If you want to build the variable name dynamically you'd need to do something like ...

```
1.times {|i| puts "current $#{i} is #{eval '$'+i.to_s}"}
```

Comment: Oh true - now it looks quite obvious. Thanks for the answer!